# Problem reduction: Can YES-Instances also be mapped to NO-Instances if there is perfect correspondence?

Tags: reductions, decision-problem, polynomial-time-reductions

> **Definition**: Problem A is reducible to problem B if an algorithm for solving
> problem B efficiently (if it existed) could also be used as a
> subroutine to solve problem A efficiently. When this is true, solving
> A cannot be harder than solving B. In these reductions, a YES instance
> of A maps to a YES instances of B and NO instances of A maps to a NO
> instances of B.

I want to focus on the part that a YES-Instance of A must be mapped to a YES-instance of B (and the same for NO-Instances).

For some problem I currently study I found a reduction which I am not sure of if it is allowed and follows the rules of reductions.

What I did was that I mapped the YES-instances of A to the NO-instances of B, (and the NO-instances of A to the YES-instances of B).

Is this allowed? I assume that i could just change the definition of Problem B to exactly exchange YES-Instances and NO-Instances, but I am somewhat unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exact definition of reduction that you are using. What you describe is not a many-one reduction, but (assuming that your reduction is computable) it is a Turing reduction.

Whether that's useful of not depends on what you're trying to prove. For example polynomial-time Turing reductions (called Cook reductions) are still useful to provide evidence that a problem can be solved easily / might be hard to solve but are less refined than polynomial time many-one reductions. i.e., Karp reductions (e.g., if you have a Cook reduction from a NP-Hard problem A to a problem B, then you cannot conclude that B is NP-hard).

Comment: As Im extremely unsure about reductions: Can you point out the difference between a many-one reduction and (my) Turing reduction? Also what is the difference regarding complexity results? 

For my part I wanted to show hardness of B by using a problem A (which is known to be hard), and reducing A to B. Is this possible by what my question explained?

Comment: A many-one reduction is a computable function that maps yes instances of $A$ to yes instances of $B$ and no instances of $A$ to no instances of $B$. Your Turing reduction does no have this property, so it's not a many-one reduction. Is problem $B$ difficult to state? Depending on it's definition, it might not be hard to prove that $B$ is NP-Hard or Co-NP-Hard using Karp reductions.

Comment: What kind of hardness do you want so show? If we are talking about NP-hardness then your reduction is not sufficent to establish that B is NP-Hard. However, assuming that your Turing reduction requires polynomial time (i.e., it is a Cook reduction) and that $A$ is NP-hard then you'd  still be providing a strong evidence that $B$ might be difficult to solve efficiently (a polynomial-time algorithm for $B$ would immediately provide a polynomial-time algorithm for $A$ and hence for all problems in NP. This would be a major breakthrough since it would show that $P=NP$).

Comment: I'am actually looking into parameterized reductions (where the same YES to YES correspondence is needed). You mention that if my reduction requires polynomial time (which mine does) there would be "strong evidence". Does this strong evidence correspond to some complexity class (not necessarily regarding parameterized reductions)?

Comment: You can just say that $B$ is NP-hard (or NP-complete, if $B$ is also in $NP$) with respect to Cook reductions. I don't know if there is a short name for this class.

Answer (score 0):

> What I did was that I mapped the YES-instances of A to the NO-instances of B, (and the NO-instances of A to the YES-instances of B).

I was actually looking into this recently! This is a common type of reduction, but to my knowledge, there isn't a standard separate name for it. Instead, complexity theorists usually describe this as either:

- A **many-one reduction from $A$ to $B^C$**, or
- A **Turing reduction from $A$ to $B$.**

It's really much more restricted than a Turing reduction; a general Turing reduction uses an oracle for B as a subroutine to solve A, and may use several queries to B (and negate or process their answers). So a Turing reduction could potentially do a lot more than simply making one query to B and negating the result, which is what you are doing here.

So I would favor the "many-one reduction from $A$ to $B^C$" terminology, as that is more specific and clearly describes what you mean.